# Autofac Exception: Cannot resolve parameter of constructor 'Void .ctor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I have the following error:

> ExceptionMessage=None of the constructors found with
>   'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
>   'RestAPI.DevelopersController' can be invoked with the available
>   services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter
>   'Services.DevelopersService userService' of constructor 'Void
>   .ctor(Services.DevelopersService)'.

**Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings();
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterModule(new ServiceModule());
        builder.RegisterModule(new ORMModule());
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).PropertiesAutowired();
        var container = builder.Build();
        var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
    }
```

**ServiceModule.cs**

```
public class ServiceModule : Autofac.Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("Services"))
                 .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
                 .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                 .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```

**ORMModule.cs**

```
public class ORMModule : Autofac.Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType(typeof(DatabaseContext)).As(typeof(DbContext)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```

**DevelopersController**

```
public class DevelopersController : ApiController
{
    private DevelopersService _developersService;

    public DevelopersController(DevelopersService userService)
    {
        _developersService = userService;
        _developersService.SetIdentity(HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.ToString().Substring(4));
    }
```

**DevelopersService.cs**

```
public class DevelopersService : IService<User>
{
    private DatabaseContext _db;

    public DevelopersService(DatabaseContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public void SetIdentity(string username)
    {

    }

    public User Create(User entity)
    {
        return new User();
    }
    public User Read(User Id)
    {
        return new User();
    }
    public void Update(User user)
    {

    }
    public void Delete(User Id)
    {

    }
    public IEnumerable<User> GetAll()
    {
        return _db.Users.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

**IService.cs**

```
public interface IService<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    void SetIdentity(string identity);
    T Create(T entity);
    T Read(T Id);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T Id);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: are ServiceModule.cs and DevelopersService.cs in same assembly/project ? if yes can you simply the module something like this and try.

 builder.RegisterType<DevelopersService>()
                   .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                   .SingleInstance();

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This error message occurs when *Autofac* try to instantiate a `DevelopersController`. In order to create a new `DevelopersController` it have to provide an instance `DevelopersService` but none of them are registered in *Autofac*.

Eeven if the following piece of code

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("Services"))
       .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

register a `DevelopersService` in *Autofac*, it doesn't register it as a `DevelopersService` but as implemented interfaces (ie `IService<User>`)

In order to fix your issue, you can change your registration to register the service as itself

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("Services"))
       .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
       .AsSelf()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

or change your `DevelopersController` to not rely on `DevelopersService` but on `IService<USer>`

```
public class DevelopersController : ApiController
{
    private IService<USer> _userService;

    public DevelopersController(IService<USer> userService)
    {
        _userService= userService;
        _userService.SetIdentity(HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.ToString().Substring(4));
    }
```

I would recommend this solution.

Answer (score 6):

OK so I'm using nopcommerce, and in my dependancy registrar I have a type

Had typed:

```
builder.RegisterType<CustomerReturnsService>().As<CustomerReturnsService>();
```

Supposed to be

```
builder.RegisterType<CustomerReturnsService>().As<ICustomerReturnsService>();
```

Notice the `I` in last customer returns service. It links to the interface of the service.

Answer (score 0):

hope my answer still helps, I think the problem is the lack of reference the DevelopersService class which maybe located at other project. Try the code below.

```
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(DevelopersService).Assembly)
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();
```