# How to register typed httpClient service with autofac?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, httpclient, autofac

I'm creating MVC web application which calls an api using .net core 2.2 using separate `HttpClient`s to call each controller (same api).

Ex:

- For user controller actions : UserService (httpclient)
- For post controller actions : PostService (httpclient)

In **`startup.cs`** I use DI as:

```
services.AddHttpClient<IUserService, UserService>();
services.AddHttpClient<IPostService, PostService>();
```

In my handler :

```
public class CommandHandler : IRequestHandler<Command, BaseResponse>
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public CommandHandler(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public Task<BaseResponse> Handle(Command request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But when invoking command handler I get this error:

> None of the constructors found with
>   'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
>   'xxx.Application.Services.Users.UserService' can be invoked with
>   the available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter
>   'System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient' of constructor 'Void
>   .ctor(System.Net.Http.HttpClient,
>   xxx.Application.Configurations.IApplicationConfigurations,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[xxx.Application.Services.Users.UserService])'.

But I've registered services in autofac module:

```
public class ServiceModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ServiceModule).Assembly)
                .Where(t => t.Namespace.StartsWith("xxx.Application.Services"))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```

Here is my `UserService` class constructor:

```
public UserService (HttpClient httpClient, IApplicationConfigurations applicationConfig, ILogger<UserService> logger)
{
    _httpClient = httpClient;
    _applicationConfig = applicationConfig;
    _logger = logger;

    _remoteServiceBaseUrl = $"{_applicationConfig.WebApiBaseUrl}";
}
```

I have two questions:

1. What does the above error mean?
2. Is it good practice to use separate httpclients for different controllers in api?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the error.  Autofac cannot instantiate `UserService` because one of constructor parameters is `HttpClient` which you have not registered.  The error has nothing to do with `CommandHandler`.  You should include your constructor code for `UserService`.

Comment: thanks.
i have included it in question(updated)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Autofac Exception: Cannot resolve parameter of constructor 'Void .ctor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31477287/autofac-exception-cannot-resolve-parameter-of-constructor-void-ctor)

Comment: Registration order is important. See: https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/934

Comment: could you share more code from your startup.cs file ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand yes i can what do you need from startup?

Comment: @Roshan how do you configure autofac to .net core logic ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By doing

```
services.AddHttpClient<IUserService, UserService>();
```

You will configure the native .net core dependency injection to inject `HttpClient` to `UserService` when a `IUserService` is requested.

Then you do

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ServiceModule).Assembly)
       .Where(t => t.Namespace.StartsWith("xxx.Application.Services"))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

which will erase the native dependency injection configuration for `IUserService`. The `IUserService` is now registered with `UserService` without any `HttpClient` in mind.

The simplest way to add `HttpClient` would be to register it like this :

```
builder.Register(c => new HttpClient())
       .As<HttpClient>();
```

or

```
services.AddHttpClient(); // register the .net core IHttpClientFactory 
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient())
       .As<HttpClient>();
```

If you want to configure your httpclient for a specific service you can create an autofac module which add parameters like this :

```
public class HttpClientModule<TService> : Module
{
    public HttpClientModule(Action<HttpClient> clientConfigurator)
    {
        this._clientConfigurator = clientConfigurator;
    }

    private readonly Action<HttpClient> _clientConfigurator;

    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        base.AttachToComponentRegistration(componentRegistry, registration);

        if (registration.Activator.LimitType == typeof(TService))
        {
            registration.Preparing += (sender, e) =>
            {
                e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Union(
                  new[]
                  {
                    new ResolvedParameter(
                        (p, i) => p.ParameterType == typeof(HttpClient),
                        (p, i) => {
                            HttpClient client = i.Resolve<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient();
                            this._clientConfigurator(client);
                            return client;
                        }
                    )
                  });
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Then

```
builder.RegisterModule(new HttpClientModule<UserService>(client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.XXX.com/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.XXX.v3+json");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "HttpClientFactory-XXX");
}));
```

Comment: great code, but not compatible with Autofac 6.

Answer (score 6):

Cyril's implementation of using an Autofac module works wonderfully, but unfortunately is not compatible with Autofac 6.0+.

In order to configure an `HttpClient` in Autofac 6.0+ for a specific service, an Autofac middleware needs to be implemented:

```
public class HttpClientMiddleware<TService> : IResolveMiddleware
{
    private readonly Action<HttpClient> _clientConfigurator;

    public HttpClientMiddleware(Action<HttpClient> clientConfigurator)
    {
        _clientConfigurator = clientConfigurator;
    }

    public PipelinePhase Phase => PipelinePhase.ParameterSelection;

    public void Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action<ResolveRequestContext> next)
    {
        if (context.Registration.Activator.LimitType == typeof(TService))
        {
            context.ChangeParameters(context.Parameters.Union(
                new[]
                {
                    new ResolvedParameter(
                        (p, _) => p.ParameterType == typeof(HttpClient),
                        (_, i) => {
                            var client = i.Resolve<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient();
                            _clientConfigurator(client);
                            return client;
                        }
                    )
                }));
        }

        next(context);
    }
}
```

Then the service can be registered, utilizing the middleware:

```
builder.RegisterType<UserService>()
    .As<IUserService>()
    .ConfigurePipeline(p =>
    {
        p.Use(new HttpClientMiddleware<UserService>(client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.XXX.com/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.XXX.v3+json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "HttpClientFactory-XXX");
        }));
    });
```

Comment: The new pipeline step is never called when injecting UserService? Is there any other steps needed?

Answer (score 3):

You can register any type with httpclient as follows extension method.

```
public static ContainerBuilder RegisterWithHttpClient<TInterface, TClass>(this ContainerBuilder builder, Action<IComponentContext, HttpClient> config)
        where TClass: class
    {
        builder
            .RegisterType<TClass>()
            .AsSelf()
            .As<TInterface>()
            .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
                (info, context) => info.ParameterType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(HttpClient)),
                (info, context) =>
                {
                    var httpClient = context.Resolve<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient();
                    config.Invoke(context, httpClient);

                    return httpClient;
                }
            ))
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        return builder;
    }
```

and register your type.

```
    //in startup.cs or autofac module.
    public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder container)
    {
        container.RegisterWithHttpClient<IEmailSender, MyEmailSender>((context, client) =>
        {
            var settings = context.Resolve<IOptionsSnapshot<EmailSenderSettings>>().Value;
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"{settings.ApiBaseUrl.TrimEnd('/')}/");
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(settings.TimeoutSeconds);
        });
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the most recent answer as well as the simplest. I would only add that it is still a prerequisite to call `services.AddHttpClient()` on your `IServiceCollection` so that the client and factory dependencies are correctly preregistered.