# How i use autofac in asp.net zero

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I want to use autofac in asp.net zero.
here is my code.

```
public class BlackPearShip : HealthAppServiceBase, IBlackPearShip  
{
            private readonly HttpClient _blackpearVISIONPostback;
    
            public BlackPearShip(IIndex<string, HttpClient> blackShipFhir)
            {
                _blackpearVISIONPostback= blackShipFhir["BlackPearFHIR"];
            }
}
```

But I am getting this error
[click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUeCo.png)

Comment: It looks like you haven't registered `HttpClient` with the Autofac container. In order to create `BlackPearShip` it needs to create `HttpClient`, so `HttpClient` must be registered. I think this is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58837354/5101046

Answer (score 0):

`IIndex<string, HttpClient>` is not registered properly. You should register like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<BlackPearFHIRHttpClient>().Keyed<HttpClient>("BlackPearFHIR");
```