# Configuring HttpClient and IHttpClientFactory in Autofac using autofac.json

Tags: httpclient, .net-6.0, autofac

I'm working on an ASP.NET project using Autofac for dependency injection, and I have a service that relies on **`HttpClient`**. I've registered **`IHttpClientFactory`** in my **`Startup.cs`** and use it to create **`HttpClient`** instances for various purposes.
I want to move the configuration of **`HttpClient`** and **`IHttpClientFactory`** to **`autofac.json`** to centralize the registration and to keep my Autofac configuration organized. However, I'm unsure of how to correctly configure **`HttpClient`** in **`autofac.json`** to utilize **`IHttpClientFactory`**.

I've registered **`HttpClient`** in my **`Startup.cs`**:

```
builder.Register(ctx =>
            {
                var services = new ServiceCollection();
                services.AddHttpClient();
                var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                return provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
                                .CreateClient("HomeSubscriberServiceHttpClient");
            }).As<HttpClient>();
```

I'm looking for guidance on how to correctly configure **`HttpClient`** and **`IHttpClientFactory`** in **`autofac.json`** to achieve the desired setup. Any insights, solutions, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/58837354/1539100 make helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I do not know accurate answer of your question, but I think the below answer can resolve your problem.*

---

If you want to registration types, based on specific condition, and want to use configuration file only. you have to use [Autofac Module](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/modules.html)

I add some example in https://github.com/soroshsabz/TestSolution

but for further explanation I add this example below

First of all, I write a simple module for specify conditions of dependency loading, like below

```cs
using Autofac;

namespace AutofacHandyMVCTest.Modules
{
    public class HttpModule : Module
    {
        public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            base.Load(builder);

            if (IsEnabled)
            {
                builder.Register(ctx =>
                {
                    var services = new ServiceCollection();
                    services.AddHttpClient();
                    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                    return provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
                                    .CreateClient("HomeSubscriberServiceHttpClient");
                }).As<HttpClient>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I write some configuration like below

```json
{
  "modules": [
    {
      "type": "AutofacHandyMVCTest.Modules.HttpModule, AutofacHandyMVCTest",
      "properties": {
          "IsEnabled": false
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

as you can see, if I want to load `HttpClient` I just need to make `IsEnabled` properties true in configuration file.