# Autofac Issue: Cannot resolve parameter of constructor 'Void .ctor

Tags: c#, .net, autofac, mediatr

My .Net 7 application has the following issue:

```
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating MyApp.Modules.MyModule.Application.MyModule.UpdateCommand.UpdateCommandHandler.
 ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'MyApp.Modules.MyModule.Infrastructure.Configuration.AllConstructorFinder' on type 'MyApp.Modules.MyModule.Application.MyModule.UpdateCommand.UpdateCommandHandler' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'MyApp.Modules.MyModule.Application.Contracts.IMyModule myModule' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Serilog.ILogger, MyApp.Modules.MyModule.Application.Contracts.IMyModule)'.
```

UpdateCommandHandler.cs (where the issue is occurring)

```
public class UpdateCommandHandler: ICommandHandler<UpdateCommand>
{
    private readonly IMyModule _myModule;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public UpdateCommandHandler(ILogger logger, IMyModule myModule)
    {
        _myModule = myModule;
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public async Task<Unit> Handle(UpdateCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var foo = await _myModule.ExecuteQueryAsync(new SampleQuery());
        return Unit.Value;
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
...

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());
builder.Host.ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(b => b.RegisterModule(new AutofacModules()));

...
```

I looked at similar issues before posting, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31477287/autofac-exception-cannot-resolve-parameter-of-constructor-void-ctor), but I do believe I appropriately registered IMyModule in Autofac as MyModule in the following.

AutofacModules.cs

```
public class AutofacModules: Autofac.Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<MyModule>().As<IMyModule>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```

IMyModule.cs

```
public interface IMyModule
{    
    Task ExecuteCommandAsync(ICommand command);

    Task<TResult> ExecuteQueryAsync<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query);
}
```

MyModule.cs

```
public class MyModule: IMyModule
{    
    public async Task ExecuteCommandAsync(ICommand command)
    {
        await CommandsExecutor.Execute(command);
    }

    public Task<TResult> ExecuteQueryAsync<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query)
    {
        var scope = MyCompositionRoot.BeginLifetimeScope();
        var mediator = scope.Resolve<IMediator>();
        return mediator.Send(query);
    }
}
```

AllConstructorFinder.cs

```
internal class AllConstructorFinder : IConstructorFinder
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ConstructorInfo[]> Cache = new();

    public ConstructorInfo[] FindConstructors(Type targetType)
    {
        var result = Cache.GetOrAdd(targetType, t => t.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredConstructors.ToArray());
        return result.Length > 0 ? result : throw new NoConstructorsFoundException(targetType);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the impression you may be over simplifying the example - the exception says you're using a custom constructor finder, for example, which isn't shown. Also, [did you see the trusting docs?](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting/exceptions/no-found-constructors-can-be-invoked.html)

Comment: Added AllConstructorFinder code. I followed the link and found it very helpful, particularly the `container.Resolve<MyApp.IMyDependency>()` snippet. Using this snippet, I debugged through my program til I found the issue, which I'll post below.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Also, ARGH AUTOCORRECT ^troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

In my Program.cs, I had registered `MyModule`, but, as I have multiple modules with their own containers, I didn't register it in the module's own composition root. By adding the following line, I'm able to include `MyModule` as a constructor parameter.

MyModuleStartup.cs

```
...
var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
...
/* NEW LINE */
containerBuilder.RegisterType<CventModule>().As<ICventModule>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
...
```

So lesson here is make sure the component you are using is registered to Autofac root container your module is running directly in. Thanks to @Travis Illig for the troubleshooting link which helped me immensely.